# What is the difference between a denomination and a movement?

Tags: terminology, movements, denomination

I grew up raised in an Apostolic(Oneness-)Pentecostal church that affirmed O.S.A.S., I was always told our denomination was Pentecostal, but I see some refer to Pentecost as a movement, and U.P.C. as a denomination. What is the difference? Is one an umbrella term for all who affirm a particular title in the name of their doctrinal beliefs group?

e.g. Would a Southern Baptist Church and a Calvary Baptist both be called: baptist in movement, but Southern Baptist for the denomination and Calvary Baptist for the denomination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **denomination** is a group of churches in a formal organisation. There is usually some kind of leadership, some kind of joint document that defines what they believe or do, and usually an official government registered corporation.

A **movement** is a group of Christians who share a particular history, set of beliefs, or set of practices. But they don't have to be united officially. There's no organisation that brings together all Protestants, or all pentecostals, or all baptists, or all creationists, or all those who are pre millennial. Some movements will define churches, others just some of the people in them.